# I need to use runOnUiThread, but a nullpointerException occurs when it's utilized

Tags: java, android

I want use `runOnUiThread` 
I know if I want to use a thread in UI group, I must use a handler, because, android UI is single thread model.

So I use `runOnUiThread`

```
public class VideoCap implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

private static TextView sTextView; //global variable
private Context context;

private VideoCap(GLSurfaceView surface, TextView textView) {
   this.context = context;
   sTextView = textView;
}


public void showText(final TextView textView) {
    sTextView = textView;
    sTextView.findViewById(R.id.text);

    ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { //NPE
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sTextView.setText("MyVideoRendererGui~~");
            sTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });

}
}
```

logcat

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.example.unno.mywebrtc.MyVideoRendererGui.showText(MyVideoRendererGui.java:90)
                                                   at com.example.unno.mywebrtc.MyVideoRendererGui.onDrawFrame(MyVideoRendererGui.java:449)
                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1535)
                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

Is it caused perhaps, by a context problem? How do I use runOnUiThread, without causing a nullpointerException?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context is null. You should do something like:

```
getApplicationContext().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
```

or

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
```

As a note, you never set the context in your constructor. You would have to do something like:

```
private VideoCap(GLSurfaceView surface, TextView textView, Context context) {
   this.context = context;
   sTextView = textView;
}
```

Also, having a private constructor only means that a method within your class can build your object, which is also why your context is null. You need to make the constructor public, or find a way to create your object from within your class.

Comment: my class not activity . so, not use`getApplicationContext().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){`

Comment: Then use `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well as your constructor is `private` it is not being called as you expect and there `context` is not being set, hence it is `null`